# Clicking on-screen keyboard with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am developing a bot to click the on-screen keyboard with pyautogui

The following is the code I am currently using to click 'a' on the keyboard.

```
import pyautogui

osk_filepath = os.path.abspath("assets")

osk_icon = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(os.path.join(osk_filepath, "OSK_ICON.png"))

if not osk_icon:
    sys.exit("Unable to detect On-Screen Keyboard")

OSK_LOCATION = (osk_icon[0] - 25, osk_icon[1], 1000, 500)

a = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(os.path.join(osk_filepath, "a.png"), region=OSK_LOCATION, grayscale=True)

pyautogui.click(a)
```

It moves the mouse to the position of the 'a' key but does not press down for it to output an 'a'.

Answer (score 5):

This issue can be solved by running the IDE as admin.